# Access VBA Insert Into Select Statement Runtime Error 3134 Syntax Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

On my form named ItemSchedule, I have a command button to add records to a table named ItemSchedule. There is a query named q_ItemFetch which only has three columns: Item, ORDER_NO, DUE_DATE.

Also, There is a dataview subform named ItemScheduleSub with the ItemSchedule table as its control source.

I am getting Runtime Error '3134'
"Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement", here's the code:

```
Private Sub cmdFetch_Click()
    If MsgBox("Do you wish to add more records of this item?", vbYesNo, "Delete Confirmation") = vbYes Then
        Dim sSQL As String
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO ItemSchedule (Item, Order, DueDate)" & _
        "SELECT (Item, ORDER_NO, DUE_DATE) " & _
        "FROM q_ItemFetch " & _
        "WHERE q_ItemFetch.ORDER_NO <> Me!ItemScheduleSub.Order;"
        DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
        Me!ItemScheduleSub.Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

I expecting that the records found in the q_ItemFetch query will be added to the ItemSchedule table. I don't see any reserved words in there.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, capture the SQL, execute it from an immediate window, observe the syntax error, fix it, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Me!ItemScheduleSub.Order needs to be evaluated, then appended to sSQL. It needs to moved out of the quotes.

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO ItemSchedule (Item, Order, DueDate)" & _
        "SELECT (Item, ORDER_NO, DUE_DATE) " & _
        "FROM q_ItemFetch " & _
        "WHERE q_ItemFetch.ORDER_NO <> " & Me!ItemScheduleSub.Order + ";"
```

Comment: @BigBen I agree. I changed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

That `INSERT` attempt has 2 problems:

1. `Order` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#O).
2. `Me` in `Me!ItemScheduleSub.Order` is meaningful to VBA in the form, but the database engine doesn't know anything about `Me`

I think the reserved word is the cause of your 3134 error.  If you rename that field or bracket it ... `[Order]` ... the error should go away.

Then resolve the issue with `Me`.  You could do that in a parameter query ...

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim sSQL As String

sSQL = "INSERT INTO ItemSchedule (Item, [Order], DueDate) " & _
    "SELECT (Item, ORDER_NO, DUE_DATE) " & _
    "FROM q_ItemFetch " & _
    "WHERE q_ItemFetch.ORDER_NO <> [which_order];"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, sSQL)
qdf.Parameters("which_order").Value = Me!ItemScheduleSub.Order
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```